# What is the white liquid they drink in several scenes?

Tags: the-bridge-of-san-luis-rey-2004

In *The Bridge of San Luis Rey* (2004), Manuel (or is it Esteban?) seals a deal by sharing a drink of white liquid. At times, people are seen drinking it from shot glasses; both of these lead me to assume it isn't milk... So what is it?

Answer (score 13):

I believe that is supposed to be [*chicha*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicha) (or [*chicha de jora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicha_de_jora)), an Andean beer-like drink made from maize.  Based on the linked description it can vary in colour from very pale to purple, depending on the colour of maize it is made from.

[image: glass of chicha de jora]

It may not be named explicitly in the movie, but it is mentioned in the [source novel](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/69768/pg69768-images.html).

> The Marquesa, beside not having heard the scurrilous songs, was in other ways unprepared for the actress's visit. You should know that after the departure of her daughter, Doña María had lighted upon a certain consolation: she had taken to drinking. **Everyone drank *chicha* in Peru** and there was no particular disgrace in being found unconscious on a feast day.